# Inline styles coming out of nowhere

Tags: jquery, if-statement, resize

**VERSION 1. EDITED VERSION BELOW**

This is a **very** basic representation of what I originally had, I can't seem to get it any shorter than this, so I'm sorry for the load of code. I commented where the problem might lie.

Extended Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/tKL8E/53/

As you can see, there is a menu that can be hovered. In normal view (horizontal menu) tooltips will appear which represent the title of the link (so basically, modified tooltips). When you resize the window to < 800, the menu should become vertical (media queries). The problem is, that the function that has been called inside the if-function, still works. The modified tooltip keeps appearing and being animating (instead of standard tooltips) and the arrows are still being positioned.

```
function triangleMenu() {
  var wW = $(window).width();
  if (wW > 800) {
    // Get rid of [title]'s and put them in data unless it has sub-items
    $("li:not(.has-sub-menu) > a[title]").each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.data("title", $this.attr("title"));
      $this.removeAttr("title");
    });

    // tooltip positioning on hover and overlay fade on all li's
    $("nav li").hover(function () {
      // Bunch of vars

      if (
      ($this.parent("ul:not(.sub-menu)").length || ($this.parent("ul.sub-menu").length && $this.is(":last-child"))) && !$this.hasClass("has-sub-menu")) {

        tooltip.stop(true).css("right", "auto").text(title).animate({
          "left": posL - (tooltip.width() / 2),
            "top": posT + $this.offset().top + 20
        }, 300).fadeTo(200, 1);
      } else if (!$this.is(":last-child") && $this.parent("ul.sub-menu").length) {
        var condition = offL > ((wW / 2) - $this.width()),
          properties = {},
          cssProp = {};

        tooltip.stop(true).text(title);
        if (condition) {
          properties = {
            "left": (offL - tooltip.width() - 30)
          };
        } else {
          properties = {
            "left": (offL + $this.width() + 25)
          };
        }
        $.extend(properties, {
          "top": ($this.offset().top + (posT / 2) - (tooltip.height() / 2))
        });

        tooltip.animate(properties, 300).fadeTo(200, 1); // SO TOOLTIP ANIMATES, BUT ONLY WHEN WINDOW WIDTH EXCEEDS 800
      }
    },function () {
    });
  } else { // IF WINDOW IS TIGHTER THAN 800 PX
    // Put data back
    $("li:not(.has-sub-menu) > a").each(function () {
      var $this = $(this),
        title = $this.data("title");

      $this.attr("title", title);
    });
  }
}

triangleMenu();

$(window).resize(function () {
  triangleMenu();
});
```

Again, I am sorry for the extensiveness of this example, but it is quite impossible to cut it down any further, without losing the functionality that does not work.

---

**NEW: VERSION 2**

With some help and a lot of testing and sugar-overloaded drinks, I've got the "main menu" working. The resized (mobile/responsive) menu is not working though.

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tKL8E/59/)

When resizing to the smaller menu (you might have to resize twice, smaller, larger, smaller), you should be able to open up an item that has a sub menu by clicking it, but this doesn't work. When clicking a li, the sub-items gets a bunch of inline-styles but I have no idea where they come from!

```
overflow: hidden; display: none; height: 159px; padding-top: 0px; margin-top: -2px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;
```

I think they stop the menu from showing, but I can't seem to find the cause of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your **NEW: VERSION 2**

What a import thing you are missing is that, you bind too many the same click function to `$("nav li.has-sub-menu")` while resizing.

I add a `console.log(1)` in the click handler like below:

```
    $("nav li.has-sub-menu").click(function () {                                                                               
        var $this = $(this);
        console.log(1);
        $this.children("ul.sub-menu").stop(true).slideToggle("fast");
    });
```

And it will print many `1`, which I think is not you excepte.

And what is more important, the number of calling `console.log(1);` is always even，I really don't know why. But that means your sub-menu show/hide again and again, then finally hide.)

So I unbind all click function before binding,by adding the following code. It works. see [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/tKL8E/60/)

```
$("nav li.has-sub-menu").unbind("click");
```

Then another point I want to say, in function `triangleMenu`, all the code would be executed many times while resizing.

So I think we may add a boolean variable here to save it is now `> 800` or `< 800`, so we can execute all the code only if this variable change.

And I perform that like below:

```
var is_mobile;

function triangleMenu(){
    var wW = $(window).width();
    if (wW > 800 && (is_mobile === undefined || is_mobile)) {
       console.log('change to pc');
       is_mobile=false;
       //your code here
    } else if(wW <=800 && !is_mobile) {
       console.log('change to mobile');
       is_mobile=true;
       //your code here
    }
}
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tKL8E/61/)** is jsfiddle.

**update**

> Do you have any idea why the clicking is recorded more than once? It's so strange?

Because while you resize the browser, `$(window).resize` will be called all the time.
You can add a `console.log` to check like the following:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    console.log('resizing');                                                                                                       
    triangleMenu();
});
```

> And could you explain the is_mobile var?

About this, you can compare the code above with your code before like below:

```
function triangleMenu(){
    var wW = $(window).width();
    if (wW > 800 ) {
       console.log('change to pc');
       //your code here
    } else {
       console.log('change to mobile');
       //your code here
    }
}
```

It will do less `console.log`, which means can save js from doing the same thing repeatedly.

And `is_mobile` means that, while `wW` is now `>800` and no matter how width exactly it is while resizing, I set `is_mobile` to `false`, so I need not to do init and bind repeatedly. Only if `wW` is first `<=800`, I set `is_mobile` to `true`, mark that I now want to change to mobile size, then do init and bind. After these, I need not do init and bind agin, as long as `wW` is `<=800`. The opposite is the same.

My English is not very good, I don't know if I explain it clear.

Comment: This works great indeed! Thanks a lot. Do you have any idea why the clicking is recorded more than once? It's so strange? And could you explain the is_mobile var? I don't really understand it! Thanks!

Comment: But the resizing does not affect the clicking, right? Because the click function only occurs **on click**? And I don't really understand the is_mobile thingy, but I'll ask that in another question. You solved my problem, so I'll give you the bounty and accept your answer as correct!

Comment: @BramVanroy resizing does not affect click, but in your code, you bind more than one times with the same function, so when click this function will be called many times. So unbinding before bind is an way easy to see.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in this matter, but I found a solution to your problem. After a lot of testing, I found that, somehow, part of your functions that were triggered in one of the if states, remained binded. I discovered that because:

1. `$(window).resize()` was triggering the function;
2. The initial windows size worked as expected;
3. But after resizing, the functionality seemed to persist.

I came to the conclusion that there was a binding issue, and I tried this and it worked: in the else statement, I added this first line `$("nav li").unbind('hover');`. That got rid of the hover function that remained binded to the element.

But then I realized that the arrows were persisting too. To deal with that I had to add two lines of code. First, I added to the else statement:
`$("ul:not(.sub-menu) > li, ul.sub-menu > li:last-child").removeClass("over-down");`.

But that was not enough, I also moved `$("ul:not(.sub-menu) > li, ul.sub-menu > li:last-child").not(":has(ul.sub-menu)").addClass("over-down");` into the `$("nav li").hover()` function, converting it to a simpler:

`$(this).addClass("over-down");`.

I don't know if it is the most elegant solution, but it seems to work. I hope that an expert could explain better this.

You might find more bugs, but I think this will help you to fix other issues with this function. Maybe changing some of the logic and steps will do a more robust code.

PS: There is still be some issues with the menu height when resizing windows in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you! Quite helpful, though not sufficient. I solved the pixel issue and a lot of others in this 'release': http://jsfiddle.net/tKL8E/58/ The main menu is working now, but the responsive (mobile) menu is not. Please do take a look.